# Collapsing knapsack, the capacity change is based on the selected items instead of the number

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, knapsack-problem, np-hard

The collapsing knapsack problem is a generalization of the ordinary knapsack problem, where the knapsack capacity is a non-increasing function of the number of items included.

Does anyone know anything (name, literature, algorithms...) about a variant where the knapsack capacity changes depending which items you select (i.e., the domain is the powerset of the items) instead of the number of items?

Comment: You mean a function of the cardinality of the power set? Out of curiosity, can you give an example of model where this appears?

Comment: The capacity depends on what set of items you selected, not its number. Let {a, b, c} being the items the capacity of knapsack is different if you try to pick-up {a}, {a,b} or {a,c}. I am sorry, the question was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

For general value of the 'capacities', I believe you will need to do some kind of enumeration on the set elements. If I understand correctly, it corrispond more or less to an arbitrary boolean that say wether a subset is feasible (the sum of the weights of its elements is lower than its capacity) or not.

A 'capacity' in the knapsack problem is something that appears at the right-hand-side of the constraint, i.e.

```
sum p_i x_i <= C
```

in the classical knapsack and

```
sum p_i x_i <= C (sum x_i)
```

in the collapsing knapsack.

Because those are linear constraint, they behave in a somehow predictible way, which avoid to look at *all* the possible combinations (the elements of the power set) to solve the problem.

Now if you have an *arbitrary* capacity value `C_J` for each element of the power set, your capacity is not a predictible function of the vector `x`, so your only way to remove a subset `J` from the list that has to be examined is if its value (`sum_J a_i x_i`) is lower than the *value* of one of the subset that you already found to be feasible (you have no information whatsoever from the capacity).

This means in particular that there is no way to model this with an integer program, because it would require at least one constraint for each `C_J` (just computing the cost for each feasible subset will be more efficient).

I would go with an enumeration algorithm and try to reduce the search tree as much as possible.

Let us order the items by non-increasing value `a_0 >= a_1 >= ... >= a_n`.

We can look all all the possible subsets by decreasing cardinality. This is because for some cardinal number `k`, you know that the best possible subset with cardinality at most `k` will have a value of `M_k = sum_{i=0}^k a_i`, so you will be able to stop your search before examining all the subsets (I can't think of another way to cut the search tree).

The algorithm would be:

Start with `M := 0` and `k=n`.

Repeat:

- find the best subset with cardinality `k` if its value `A` is better than `M`
- `M := max (A, M)`: value of the best subset found so far
- if `M >= M_{k-1}`, stop: we found the optimum
- else `k := k-1`

To search the best subset of cardinality `k`, you can use the order of the `a_i`:

- start with `{0, ..., k}` and recursively examine the subsets `{0} U J'` with `J'` a subset of cardinality `k-1` of `{1, ..., n}`,
- then examine all the subsets of the form `{1} U J'` with `J'`a subset of cardinality `k-1` of `{2, ..., n}`, etc.

As soon as you found a feasible subset, update the bound `M`.

This is again because the subsets of cardinality `k` that do not contain `a_0, ..., a_i` are bounded by `a_{i+1} + ... + a_{i+k+1}`, and you can stop as soon as this is lower than the current bound `M`.

**Note:**
I assumed no hypothesis on the capacity `C_J`. It is certainly interesting to know if the capacity are increasing in the set-theory sense, i.e. if `I` included in `J` implies `C_I <= C_J`.

Comment: Studying my problem more I understood there are some hypothesis in the C function.  
If X is a subset of Y, C(X) => C(Y). It also mean that for all X it holds that C(X) <= C(empty set).  
Besides, let C(X) = C(empty set) - f(X), then f is submodular monotone.